# Google Form App Script; Trouble Obtaining Form Response Data

Tags: google-apps-script

I think I am encountering a bug? I had a script in google sheets were it would get the submitted Google Form values and put them into a google doc table.

I have migrated my code over to the Google Form and upon submitting it doesn't seem to grab the data I entered.

```
function doTheWork(e) {  
  var timeStamp = String(e.values[0]);  
  var entryEmail = String(e.values[1]);
  var name = String(e.values[2]);
  var number = String(e.values[3]);

  var cells = [timeStamp, entryEmail, name, number];
};
```

As part of the debugging process I found this was the error, thanks to this code:

```
var name = 'Bob';
var number = '20';
var cells = [name, number];
```

Basically, manually adding the string works. But I need it to take the data from the form.

Comment: [When in Forms](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#form-submit_3) vs [when in Sheets](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#form-submit)

Comment: @tehowch So my function is already on form submit, would I need a secondary function which acts as a custom trigger to call the items? Then how would I call them in my secondary function. Could I still use 'e.values'?

Comment: No e.values in the FORM. e.values only available in the Spreadsheet.  So the question remains are you in the Form script editor or the Spreadsheet script editor. Look at the links given by @tehhowch read them carefully.

Comment: Form script editor. Reading the links currently and attempting to resolve. It's just nice to clear things up.

Answer (score 0):

I'm answering the questions because while the links in the comments above are what put me on track it did take me a while to comprehend what the documentation meant.

Here was the solution:

```
// Get the for - You could alternatively open by id.
var form = FormApp.getActiveForm();

// Get responses
var formResponses = form.getResponses();

// Loop through the filled out form to gather all of the responses
for (var i = 0; i < formResponses.length; i++) {
  // Prepare the array
  var formResponse = formResponses[i];
  // Just FYI I got the response URL because it was handy for my situation. It is not necessary code but I if anyone else gets stuck the way I did, hopefully this helps
  var editUrl = String(formResponse.getEditResponseUrl());
  var itemResponses = formResponse.getItemResponses();
  // My form had two fields for this test. Name & Number. Here is how I was able to access the answers.
  var name = itemResponses[0].getResponse();
  var number = itemResponses[1].getResponse();
}
```